# yii select2 plugin preload data

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, jquery-select2

How could I set pre-selected data in **yii-select2** in **yii** like this example

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html#locked-selections

here is my code , and I want to display another array for pre-selected data

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
'asDropDownList' => false,

'name' => 'YumProfile[projectlist]',
'options' => array(
    'multiple' => true,
    'data' => $array,   

    'width' => '40%',
    'tokenSeparators' => array('##', ' ')
)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like YiiBooster in use. I wish you try this:

```
$array =  array(
            'active'  => 'Active',
            'pending' => 'Pending',
            'invited' => 'Invited',
            'deleted' => 'Deleted'
        )

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
    'asDropDownList' => false,
    'name' => 'YumProfile[projectlist]',
    'data' => $array,
    ...
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'options' => array( // selected options by default
        'active' => array(
                'selected' => true,
            )
        )
    ),
)
);
```

I also did the same thing with [Yii Select2 Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/), but with a little different approach.

Comment: thank you for your replay first ! my data is a 2d array like this : <code>$array2 =  array(
   array("id"=>"1",'text'=>"mm"),
            array("id"=>"2",'text'=>"mm2"),
   array("id"=>"2",'text'=>"mm3"),
        );<code> how could I set html option for these array for selected=true ?!

Comment: Okey got it ;) thank you so much , I was change my implimation on data